# Рекурсия и ее проблемы

Tags: рекурсия, алгоритм

К каким проблемам может привести использование рекурсии и как их избежать?

Comment: Метод борьбы -- не втыкать с условиями выхода из рекурсии

Comment: Солидарен с последним комментарием =)

Comment: @Gorets Чего не надо втыкать? И куда?

Comment: Имеется введу - писать код так чтобы условие окончания работы рекурсивной функции срабатывало всегда. (avoid infinity)

А если речь идет о переполнении стека, тогда ИМХО код нужно переписывать так чтобы ее вообще не было, т.к. переполнение стека как-бы указывает на то, что это место не мешало-бы переписать.

Comment: А автору не мешало бы уточнить для чего именно он собирается использовать рекурсию, тогда бы ему могли бы дать ответ вида - в вашем случае используйте и не заморачивайтесь, либо - могут возникнуть проблемы, лучше сделайте так-то так-то. Сейчас же вопрос больше похож на философское размышление о высоких материях программирования

Comment: Лучший способ избежать негативных последствий рекурсии - избегать рекурсии. Вместо нее стараться использовать циклы.

Comment: Согласен на все 100. Но у рекурсии есть 1 огромный плюс, а именно - скорость написания кода.

Comment: Лучше немного потратить дополнительного времени (не так уж и много) на составление цикла, чем мучиться с переполнением стека и прочими прелестями.

Comment: но с рекурсией - красиво =)
объясню что подразумеваю.
красиво - это "заставить" код вызывать сам себя столько раз - сколько это понадобится, чем "заставить", кого то (цикл) вызывать код эн-раз

Comment: Красиво. Угу. Эстетствуете, батенька?

Comment: @mikillskegg, стараюсь только.... Просто рекурсия - это не тот случай, когда "лучше избегать из-за непонимания", лучше разобраться и пользоваться.

Comment: Дело не в непонимании. Дело в снижении эффективности кода и в потенциальных проблемах его надежности

Comment: Ну тогда уже надо рассматривать более конкретные задачи, просто в задачах, типа поиск факториала, или более бытовой - поиск файла в папках, и с остальными такого типа, грех отказываться от рекурсии.

Comment: @mikillskegg чтоб вам программировать на языках без циклов.

Answer (score 2):

Оверхед на вызовы. Немного время, а главное -- стек. При большой глубине рекурсии быстро расходуется. Метод борьбы -- использование хвостовой рекурсии, которую нормальные компиляторы трансформируют в итерации.

Добавлено. На тему "заменить рекурсию стеком".
Рекурсивная функция вычисления факториала.
fact.c++

```
int fact0(int k, int n) {
    if (n > 1) return fact0(k*n, n-1); 
    else return k;
}
```

fact0.s

```
    .file   "fact0.c++"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl _Z5fact0ii
    .type   _Z5fact0ii, @function
_Z5fact0ii:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    movl    12(%ebp), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl    $1, %edx
    jg  .L5
    jmp .L2
    .p2align 4,,7
    .p2align 3
.L7:
    movl    %ecx, %edx
.L5:
    leal    -1(%edx), %ecx
    imull   %edx, %eax
    cmpl    $1, %ecx
    jne .L7
.L2:
    popl    %ebp
    .p2align 4,,2
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _Z5fact0ii, .-_Z5fact0ii
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Что тут заменять и на что?

Answer (score 1):

Слишком глубокую рекурсию всегда можно заменить используя стэк.

Comment: ИМХО - не можно а **нужно**

Comment: Может и так =)

Comment: Что имеется в виду по стеком?

Comment: Видимо данные в стеке, стандартный приём при работе с рекурсивными структурами (наприме, деревьями). Но экономия памяти будет только если фреймы стека рекурсивной функции существенно больше данных. Ну и другой вариант -- стековые структуры (связные или нет) в куче.